# Check boxes stop working when checked and unchecked jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, progress-bar

I have a progress bar linked to check boxes, when I check then uncheck a box, the box becomes broken and does not update on the progress bar. From what I read you can use a loop to fix this, but I am struggling to see how, any help or fixes to y solution would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**Just change:**

```
if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
  $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked');
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
} else {
  $(this).removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
}
```

**to**

```
if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
  $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked');
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
} else {
  $(this).removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

I updated the jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/UznQe/11/